# How to cut decimal number like this using php?

Tags: php, decimal

How to cut decimal number like this using php ?

`1.20` cut decimal number to `1.2`

`1.00` cut decimal number to `1`

`1.02` do not cut decimal number

I tried using `round` , `ceil` , `floor` but not work

How can i do that ?

Comment: you dont need to do anything php is smart enough it will directly change your number/string after processing. directly output them and see the result

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`floatval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) as

```
echo floatval('1.20');// 1.2

echo floatval('1.00');// 1

echo floatval('1.02');//1.02
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/383771)